# Search and return multiple key and value if value is in defined range

Tags: php, arrays, range

So, I'm stuck at this problem: I have an associative array with values like this:

```
 $age = array("Brian"=>"25","Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", 
 "Joe"=>"43", and many more);
```

The result I'm looking for is something like this:

```
 $age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37");
```

Thus either removing Entries where the value is under/equal to 34 and entries where the value is over/equal to 38. Or to search the existing array and returning a new updated array.

I've tries ways with array_search, range, for loops, but I never get it to work. Anybody have a solution?

Comment: show your code...

Comment: use `array_filter`, and as Marcin said - you should show a code with which you have problems, not ask for somebody to implement solution for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it.

```
$age = array("Brian"=>"25","Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
function filterFun($value){

   return ($value <= 34 ) || ($value >= 38 );
}

$items =  array_filter($age, "filterFun");

var_dump($items);
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me on the right track! Will present my code next time. I had to change to this for it to work: return ($value >= 34 ) && ($value <= 38 );